# BigDecimal.movePointRight() hangs with very large numbers

Tags: java, bigdecimal

The following program freezes, and I can't work out why.

```
import java.math.*;

public class BigDec {
  public static BigDecimal exp(double z) {
       // Find e^z = e^intPart * e^fracPart.
       return new BigDecimal(Math.E).pow((int)z, MathContext.DECIMAL128).
           multiply(new BigDecimal(Math.exp(z-(int)z)), MathContext.DECIMAL128);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       // This works OK:
       BigDecimal x = new BigDecimal(3E200);
       System.out.println("x=" + x);
       System.out.println("x.movePointRight(1)=" + x.movePointRight(1));

       // This does not:
       x = exp(123456789);
       System.out.println("x=" + x);
       System.out.println("x.movePointRight(1)=" + x.movePointRight(1)); //hangs
   }
}
```

For the present purposes, the first method just creates a very large BigDecimal. (Details: it finds e to the power of z, even when this too large to be a double. I am pretty sure this method is correct, though the MathContexts may not be in the best places.)

I know e^123456789 is extremely big, but I really do want to use numbers like this. Any answers would be very gratefully received.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact it does not freeze, but the implementation of `movePointRight` in Oracle's VM can be extremely inefficient. It is often much faster to multiply or divide with a power of 10 instead of using the `movePointRight` or `movePointLeft` methods. In your case, using `x.multiply(BigDecimal.TEN)` will probably work much better.

Comment: Thank you. That sounds convincing, and `x.multiply(BigDecimal.TEN)` works fine. I left my program on over the weekend (by accident), and it still hadn't finished on Monday morning, so `movePointRight` must be not just extremely but unbelievably inefficient. All it has to do is change the BigDecimal's "scale" by 1, so this is quite puzzling.

Comment: I haven't checked the entire implementation, but at some point, movePointXYZ creates an intermediate BigInteger instance in the order of 10 to the power of (number of digits in the BigDecimal). It creates a String (actually a char[]) with a leading '1', followed by some 53 million '0' characters and passes this to the BigInteger constructor. The BigInteger implementation then tries to pack this number binary encoded into 32 bit chunks in an internal int array and that is the actual culprit.